# How to prevent apps from reloading...?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

In my phone (Moto E2 running on 5.0.2) while I'm using facebook, I found a frequent reloading issue.

The problem happens only when I go to an external link to read some articles and after switching back to the app it shows only a white background and it load from the top, previously it used to show from where I left off, first I thought it may be bug in facebook app, then I noticed all my apps are having such a crazy reloading problem, another example is google plus, but luckily after reloading it show from where I left off..!

It can be a virus issue or a setting issue, so before I reset my phone I would like to know if there is a tweak or solution for this...

Answer (score 1):

Might be a problem with the device's firmware - to be more specific with the LMK (low memory killer) which is part of the Android System. I have heard of quite a few Motorola devices with multitasking problems. A good article about memory management / the LMK and OOM on android can be found [**here**](https://01.org/android-ia/user-guides/android-memory-tuning-android-5.0-and-5.1).

> Google’s OOM_ADJ values for devices with limited physical memory (512 MB) will allow the LMK to kill the foreground process (running application) after the ZRAMis filled and all cached applications (previous foreground apps) as well as the restartable background processes have been killed

Furthermore there various issues have been submitted to [**google**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=98332) and they seem to have partially fixed these issues in android 5.1. Most custom roms seem to have addressed these issues aswell. You might want to update to the [**latest available build**](https://motorola-mobility-en-in.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/105293) for your device to increase your multitask performance.

> Actually, the issue is not entirely fixed in 5.1.1. The activity manager keeps killing and restarting tasks even in CM12.1. Its just that the killing is not as aggressive as it was in 5.0.x, and after some uptime, the system does attain a sort of steady state, where killings and restarts are very few.